# How to use many checkbox values in a Query

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

My goal is to return the results of 5 textboxes into a SQL query, by incorporating the Query string with the variables.

How can I get my code to function so that when a checkbox is checked, the value (eg: ID, SC...) is recorded and placed into a Query? And if a checkbox is not checked, then it is not placed into the query.

The 5 checkboxes are as follows:

[image: Checkbox picture]

The code I current have to record whether a textbox is selected, and to place the value (eg: ID, SC, AS...) into a variable is as follows:

```
If (Me.BoxID = False) And (Me.BoxSC = False) And (Me.BoxASSC = False) And (Me.BoxAS = False) And (Me.BoxEH = False) Then
MsgBox "You must check a Fonction Checkbox", 0
Exit Sub
Else
    If (Me.BoxID= True) Then IDValue = Chr(34) & "ID" & Chr(34) Else IDValue = """"""
    If (Me.BoxSC= True) Then SCValue = Chr(34) & "SC" & Chr(34) Else SCValue = """"""
    If (Me.BoxASSC= True) Then ASSCValue = Chr(34) & "ASSC" & Chr(34) Else ASSCValue = """"""
    If (Me.BoxAS= True) Then ASValue = Chr(34) & "AS" & Chr(34) Else ASValue = """"""
    If (Me.BoxEH= True) Then EHValue = Chr(34) & "EH" & Chr(34) Else EHValue = """"""
End If

fonctionQryString = "(((tblF.f1)=" & IDValue & ") OR " + "((tblF.f1)=" & SCValue & ") OR " + "((tblF.f1)=" & ASSCValue & ") OR " + "(tblF.f1)=" & ASValue & ") OR " + "(tblF.f1)=" & EHValue & ")))"
```

The fonctionQryString goes into the WHERE section of the SQL Query.

I know that the method I'm using is not efficient, even though it works.

My problem is that I don't know how to do this another way. I want my code to function so that when a checkbox is not checked, it doesn't go into the Query string.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two `WHERE` clauses should produce equivalent results.  Consider switching to the second form.

```
WHERE tblF.f1 = "ID" OR tblF.f1 = "SC" OR tblF.f1 = "AS"
WHERE tblF.f1 IN ("ID","SC","AS")
```

Here is a rough and untested code sample to produce a similar `WHERE` clause based on my understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

```
Dim fonctionQryString As String
Dim lngLoopNum As Long
Dim strControlName As String
Dim strValueList As String
For lngLoopNum = 1 To 5
    Select Case lngLoopNum
    Case 1
        strControlName = "ID"
    Case 2
        strControlName = "SC"
    Case 3
        strControlName = "ASSC"
    Case 4
        strControlName = "AS"
    Case 5
        strControlName = "EH"
    End Select
    If Me.Controls("Box" & strControlName) = True Then
        strValueList = strValueList & "," & Chr(34) & _
            strControlName & Chr(34)
    End If
Next
If Len(strValueList) > 0 Then
    fonctionQryString = "tblF.f1 IN (" & Mid(strValueList, 2) & ")"
Else
    MsgBox "You must check a Fonction Checkbox"
End If
```

I assumed you didn't actually want to include the condition, `WHERE tblF.f1 = ""` (an empty string).  If I guessed wrong, you'll have more work to do, but hopefully this will still point you to something useful.

Comment: You're correct in assuming that I don't want to include the empty string (`tblF.f1 = ""`). I didn't know about the `IN` expression, and your code is very helpful, thank you!